# How to loop in a table to obtain the row where value x is contained (within a range)?

Tags: javascript

```
 var myTable = [

        [20,22], [22.9, 32],
        [33, 35], [37, 40],
        [42, 44], [45, 47]
       ];

var min = 0;
var max = 100;
var x = 23;

function between(x, min, max) {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  }
 
function GetCellValues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
        for (var f = 0, q = myTable.rows.legnth; f < q; f++) { 
        for (var g = 0, t = myTable.rows[f].cells.length; g < t; g++) {
        

 // TEst if x is between 2 values in the table  

        for (var m = 0, n = 3; m < n; n++) {
            if (between(x, arrValues[f], arrValues[g])) {
                console.log(Boolean(between));
                min = arrValues[f]
                max = arrValues[g] 
           }
            else
               console.log("NOT TRUE");
        }
            }
    }
}; 
       
    console.log(myTable[min,max]);
```

I would like to search into a table (1st column) to see if there is a match between a value X and the provided range in the table i.e. [22, 24]. That is the first step.
The error message I get : "undefined".

Comment: Your code is trying to log `myTable[min,max]`, where `min,max` evaluates to `100` (because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)). This means you're logging `myTable[100]` but `myTable` only has six elements. You therefore get `undefined`.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/twf9uvxg/

Comment: Yes, that works. Still learning Javascript.